# Obtaining Source Code Repository Info During Maven Build

Tags: maven, svn

What are some ways to obtain source code repository info during a maven build? I'm familiar with the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html), but am looking to obtain additional info, not only "build number".

Specifically, my source code repository is subversion. The type of info I'm looking to obtain is contained in these [subversion keyword values](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-keywords.html). Is there a way to obtain these, or similar info, during a maven build, perhaps using a maven plugin designed for that purpose?

Comment: Why do you need them?

Comment: Looking for a way to obtain the repository info (ver info etc.) during maven compile.

Comment: Better use the build-number-maven-plugin and get those information like revision from there but not via the keywords. Apart from that those keywords you have linkes are only for TortoiseSVN Client but *NOT* for [Subversion in general](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html). What usually makes sense is to use the svn revision and the branch. But what about the other things?